# How to retrieve only names from oc get dc (openshift cli get deployment configurations)?

Tags: openshift

Using the openshift cli ("oc") we can retrieve a list of deployment configurations within the current project with:

```
$/> oc get dc
```

I'd like to itereate over that list and query certain properties on the "oc describe [dcname]" for each deployment config.

What's a convenient way of doing that?

Comment: What properties are you trying to extract?

Comment: The goal is to retrieve secrets and configmaps volumeMounts by deployment config. In my case I can assume that there is only one container definition per deployment config.

Answer (score 5):

You can get just the names by using:

```
oc get dc -o name
```

You may though also want to look at using `-o template` and provide a template spec to extract the various settings you want.

```
oc get dc -o template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}},{{index .metadata.labels "app"}}{{"\n"}}{{end }}'
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try it Monday when I'm back in the office. Thanks!

Comment: with `-o name`, you may get a different name then expected which is where the template becomes handy. For a custom resource `-o name` gave me resourceType/metadata.name instead of just metadata.name. I did this instead
`oc get resource -o template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'`